# Convert an array of object with different keys to a single object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object like this

```
[
 0:{new: 'val'},
 1:{new2: 'val2'},
 2:{new3: 'val3'}
]
```

I'm trying to convert it to this form

```
{new:'val',new2:'val2',new3:'val3'}
```

I tried the related answers for similar questions and tried using

```js
var arr = [{key:"11", value:"1100"},{key:"22", value:"2200"}];
var object = arr.reduce(
  (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { [item.key]: item.value }), {});

console.log(object)
```

but that return {undefined,undefined}

Comment: Converted your code to a snippet. Problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{
    new: 'val'
  },
  {
    new2: 'val2'
  },
  {
    new3: 'val3'
  }
];
var object = arr.reduce(
  (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, item), {});

console.log(object)
```